# How to deploy to Anypoint Runtime Manager using SSO authentication?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, mulesoft, cloudhub

We use SSO authentication for our organisation Anypoint. We would like to automate deployments of Mule Maven Applications using Jenkins. There are lots of examples automating the deployment but all using username/password in the pom.xml and this doesn't work using SSO authentication. How can we automate the deploymens using SSO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two alternatives:

1. [recommended] Use a [Connected App](https://docs.mulesoft.com/access-management/connected-apps-developers) credentials as the authorization by setting the elements connectedAppClientId, connectedAppClientSecret and connectedAppGrantType in the [`<cloudHubDeployment>`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/deploy-to-cloudhub#cloudhub-deploy-reference) configuration. You have to setup the [Connected App](https://docs.mulesoft.com/access-management/connected-apps-overview) first in Access Management. This is supported by the [Mule Maven Plugin from version 3.4.0](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-maven-plugin/mule-maven-plugin-3.4.0-release-notes#features-and-functionality) and newer.
2. You can use an [authorization token](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/deploy-to-cloudhub#authentication-methods) from your identity provider as the authorization. I understand that you have to get the token somehow. That's something that you will need to understand how to do it from your identity provider.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate on the steps

Comment: I have added more details and a better alternative.

Comment: I did actually add the tags , but get the below error,

ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.4.0:deploy (default-deploy) on project staging-nova: Execution default-deploy of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.4.0:deploy failed: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/plain;charset=utf-8, type=class org.mule.tools.client.arm.model.Environments, genericType=class org.mule.tools.client.arm.model.Environments. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
Can you please advise

Comment: Did you create the connected app in access management first? I don't see the cause of the error in that. Try running maven with -X for debug information.

Comment: Yes , the App is created beforehand,The Debug information shows the same failure

Comment: Looks like it received an error message but it is not showing it. Maybe the connected app doesn't have the right permissions for CloudHub deployment?

Comment: Yes the permissions were the issue.it worked after i added the below permissions ,
Design Center Developer ,
Cloudhub Organization Admin
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the permissions needed.